# find usages of a symbol only in a specific module in Intellj

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an IntelliJ project with **several** *modules*. Is there a way to use *find usages* (for symbols - Alt+F7 in Linux) only inside a specific *module*?

For example I have two modules one is *framework* and one *app* and there's a class defined in *framework* module *FrameworkClass*.

If I see the symbol *FrameworkClass* in a class inside *app* module and click ALT+F7 I want to get all usages/references of *FrameworkClass* **only inside 'app' module**

Is there such a way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Find Usages' options dialog can be invoked with `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F7` where you can define a custom search scope, e.g. a certain module.

[image]